# An anime about a bullied girl who gets help from a "god"?

Tags: noragami

I'm searching for an anime which was released between 2013 and 2014. I am not so sure, but it seemed to be a new anime.

The plot of this anime is about a girl who has always been bullied at school. One day, when she goes to the schools toilet, she see a message on the WC door. The message comes from a boy/man/person who "is a god" (he calls himself a god). In the message, he tells the girl that he can stop the bullying and make her life better. All he wants from her is that she believes/trusts him like a god (because gods need trust/belief from humans to exist).

Answer (score 9):

You're describing the plot to the first episode of **[Noragami](http://myanimelist.net/anime/20507/Noragami)**

**[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noragami#Episode_list)** excerpt of the first episode:

> A god named Yato answers a five-yen prayer to defeat a phantom that has appeared above a school using his Regalia, Tomone.

Below is a picture of the main characters - the one with the sword is the God, Yato.

[image: Main Characters of Noragami]

Comment: I'm pretty sure the bullied person was a boy in Hiyori's class. Yato helps him after Hiyori asks him to. Hiyori herself doesn't ask help- she meets Yato when she saves his life and almost dies in the process. So I'm not sure this is the Anime, but maybe the OP got a few details wrong, in which case this answer is right

Comment: To add: That was episode 8, details https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Noragami_episodes